# Swift - Problem with constraints priority

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I currently have a layout with two large buttons, one on top of the other, and a number of icon button below them.

The second large button can appear or not. What I want is for the icon button's top constraint to be the visible large button's bottom constraint. I'm using priority to set up two constraints for the icon button:

```
    let topToBut2 = iconButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button2.bottomAnchor)
    topToBut2.isActive = true
    
    let topToBut1 = iconButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button1.bottomAnchor)
    topToBut1.priority = UILayoutPriority(500)
    topToBut1.isActive = true
```

On viewDidLoad, depending on the data available, I do

```
    button2.removeFromSuperview()
```

However, as soon as I remove button2 I get

```
'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <...> and <...> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are removing the button2:

```
button2.removeFromSuperview()
```

And thereafter you are trying to activate a constraints on it:

```
let topToBut1 = iconButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button1.bottomAnchor)
topToBut1.priority = UILayoutPriority(500)
topToBut1.isActive = true
```

So here you approach to remove the second button in order to the first button top  constraints to be active is not really good. You can instead just check if the second button should be visible and setup the iconButton constraint accordingly, without using priority or two different constraints:

```
if secondButtonVisible {
    iconButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button2.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
} else {
    iconButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button1.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

But also you should not forget to set the second button `hidden` property to false(and not just remove it from the superview), because otherwise it will be visible under iconButton.

If you are open to an other solution, as the other answer suggests here, you can use a `UIStackView` to do all the work for you. Just add the two buttons as a subView to the `UIStackView` as follows:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(button1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(button2)
```

And when you want to hide your second button you just change it's hidden property:

```
button2.isHidden = true
```

Which will hide the second button and update the layout accordingly. As per the documentation:

> The stack view automatically updates its layout whenever views are
> added, removed or inserted into the arrangedSubviews array, or
> whenever one of the arranged subviews’s isHidden property changes.

Comment: Thank you, I went ahead and changed to stackView.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding constraints and removing button, you can use stack view and add both button in it and just show and hide them as per requirements. Stackview is enrich with so many benefits so it will handle rest of the things by it's own.